# how to avoid memory storing String

Tags: java, string, security, memory, store

I'm using a java library implementation of argon2 which requires to use char array for passwords.

For testing purpose, I want to try it works before adding it to my website but I have some comprehension difficulties about how to not store String input before convert it as a char array.

Basically I'm using Eclipse IDE so I can't use the `Console console = System.console()` to use the function `console.readPassword()`. To reproduce it I'm trying something like this :

```
char[] password = new String("test").toCharArray();
```

But at this point my String is already in memory and can be catch by malicious soft, isn't it ?

the argon2 library provides a function to wipe the array, but the String would stay here, doesn't it ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to prevent the storing of the string in memory. unless you would create your password like this: `char[] password = {'t','e','s','t'};` but also this would only be useful for testing

Comment: But when I'll migrate it to my website, my servlet would probably store it as a String into the request from the login form. When I'll get it into the server side, can I wipe this from the request even if Strings are immutable ?

Comment: Is it important not to show the password characters on input? Since you're introducing it for testing purposes I guess you may accept showing the pwd characters up.

Comment: you could send a char array from the login form to the server and never even bother to handle a string

Comment: In practice, it is hard to completely avoid storing the password in a `String` somewhere in the toolchain in a web context. The web container and any frameworks you use may well handle query parameters and form fields as strings.

Comment: AlexeyR. yes this isn't a problem, my problem is at the memory level. In a web app I think the mechanism would be the same and password would be stored as String somewhere in the memory.
Lino I thinks I will do like this if html form + jsp allow me to do it
Henry Yes I think too or maybe like Lino said I can directly generate a char array from the jsp form instead of storing it as a string